# CSS combine two classes

Tags: css, class

I have 4 pictures in a horizontal line. The first 3 pictures have a `margin-right: 20px;`. Except for the last pictures which has no margin at all. This is how I did it, which I feel could be done better:

```
.threeimg {
margin-right: 20px;
border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
border-radius: 6px;
background-color: white;
padding: 8px; }


.lastimg {
border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
border-radius: 6px;
background-color: white;
padding: 8px; }
```

Any way to clean this up? Please don't be too hard on me, I literally started learning HTML&CSS 3 days ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do it like this: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/gMGkh/)

**CSS**

```
.image {
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 8px;
}
.no-margin {
    margin-right: 0;    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://goo.gl/UEZSH" class="image">
<img src="http://goo.gl/UEZSH" class="image">
<img src="http://goo.gl/UEZSH" class="image">
<img src="http://goo.gl/UEZSH" class="image no-margin">
```

#### EDIT

**Note:** The `.no-margin` class should be below the `.image` class because of the cascading nature of CSS

Answer (score 1):

I always try to write my code simple as it's possible, especially the html code. Cooperation with backend coder will be easier. I remove class no-margin and use first-child atribute. The code is below, try it.

**CSS**

```
  .image {
        margin-left: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
        width: 100px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 8px;
    }
    .image:first-child {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://goo.gl/UEZSH" class="image">
<img src="http://goo.gl/UEZSH" class="image">
<img src="http://goo.gl/UEZSH" class="image">
<img src="http://goo.gl/UEZSH" class="image">
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/ppqCD/

Answer (score 0):

Use the css pseudo-class selectors

```
img {
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 8px; 
}

img:last-child {
    margin-right:0px;
}
```

Comment: last-child is not supported in old browser

Comment: OP did not ask for compatability.

Answer (score 0):

```
.img {
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 8px; 
}

.threeimg {
    margin-right: 20px; 
}
```

We have more example here.
http://www.html5database.com/example-css.php